# Divergence of a vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For some vector field $F = f(x)i + g(y)j$, the divergence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by: $\frac{\partial {f}}{\partial {x}} + \frac{\partial {g}}{\partial {y}}$.

What happens if $f$ or $g$ is not differentiable anywhere? Is the divergence (or curl for that matter) defined? If it's not defined why is it still possible to still calculate the flux? Shouldn't it be impossible to calculate the flux since the flux is the sum of the infinitesimal divergences (intuitively) which are not defined?

Comment: You can define derivatives in a `weak' sense.

Comment: @user_of_math What do you mean by "weak sense"?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative

Answer (score 0):

Divergence can be defined for less then differentiable functions, using integration by parts against $C_c^\infty$ functions (i.e. $\int f div \phi = -\int \phi \nabla f$, where $f\in C_c^\infty$ is test function).